# How to search by category in Facebook API/FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am learning how to use search on the Facebook Graph API.

I want to format a query that will return all Facebook pages in the category `Musician/Band`.

Condsider the public page for The Beatles (https://graph.facebook.com/thebeatles), you can clearly see it as a category here.

So far, as I understand it v2.1 of the Graph API does not accept search by category, and I need to use v2.0 FQL. Is this correct?

If so, what would the correct syntax for the following pseudocode:

```
SEARCH ALL PAGES WITH CATEGORY='MUSCIAN/BAND'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to search Pages by Category unfortunately.

The query

```
select page_id, name from page where categories.name = 'Musician/Band'
```

fails with

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

although the `categories.name` is marked as indexable (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/)